# Handle the event when device connect to cradle windows ce opennetcf in C#

Tags: c#, windows-ce, device, opennetcf, cradle

I develop an application on windowCE 5.0 with opennetcf library.
I want to check WHEN my Device is connected to Cradle. It means I want to handle the event of plugged the device to cradle or other similar.

My purpose is that when Device is connected to Cradle, I disable all forms of my application,
and when it is removed from cradle, all the forms are enabled.

I search much. But the answer is not matched to my expect.

Please help me.

---

After reading reference of opennetcf, I found out the two events: ACPowerApplied and ACPowerRemoved

Here is my code:

```
public static event DeviceNotification ACPowerApplied;
public static event DeviceNotification ACPowerRemoved;

void Form1_ACPowerRemoved()
{
MessageBox.Show("Un-cradle");
}

void Form1_ACPowerApplied()
{
MessageBox.Show("Cradle");
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ACPowerApplied += new DeviceNotification(Form1_ACPowerApplied);
ACPowerRemoved += new DeviceNotification(Form1_ACPowerRemoved);
}
```

But the process did not step into Form1_ACPowerRemoved() and Form1_ACPowerApplied().

Is there any idea for that? Sorry for my poor English. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. You've subscribed to the form's event, and nobody raise it.
[Documentation](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/fafee7dd-ca96-6de7-f828-f84a547def78.htm) doesn't show how-to-use code, I think. It shows declaraion.

**Maybe** it will work (not tested):

```
OpenNETCF.WindowsCE.DeviceManagement.ACPowerApplied += Form1_ACPowerApplied
OpenNETCF.WindowsCE.DeviceManagement.ACPowerRemoved += Form1_ACPowerRemoved
```

Also you can try to use WinAPI calls: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/02/10/370591.aspx

If you want, I have complete code, but there are a lot of waste and "OnRs232Connect" event.
By the way, what does "craddled" mean for you? Craddle can be disconneted from both AC and PC. I mean, do you want to handle when your device started to get electricity power, or when it started connecting to the PC via Active Sync? If the second, you want to catch "OnRs232Connect" event